# Docker Swarm mode - equivalent docker commands to docker run -it ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-swarm

I am trying to deploy a mongodb cluster on docker swarm mode, all the mongod daemon are in the same overlay network.

I need to configure the mongodb cluster, i am trying to find a command that works like `docker run -it ubuntu` in docke rswarm mode so i can log in, any ideas?

Or is there any other way to access the overlay network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

First `ssh` to the node that runs the container, then find out the container id using `docker ps` and simply use `docker exec -it $(id) bash` to log on to the container.